# Return relationship only if user is logged in?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I have a `Posts` and a `Comments` table, where each post can have multiple comments.

I want to make a query that gets all posts, and also all of the logged in user's comments.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$posts = Post::select('posts.*')
    ->with(['comments' => function($query) {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
        }
    }])
    ->get();
```

And my `Post.php` model class looks like this:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

The query returns the correct results when the user is logged in.

But when the user is **not** logged in, it returns the comments of ALL users, instead of returning nothing (because the user is logged in and therefore they have no comments).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of to this.

First you can only load the comments if the user is logged in:

```
$posts = Post::select('posts.*');

if(Auth::check()) {
    $posts->with(['comments' => function($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
    }]);
}

$posts = $posts->get();
```

Or you could load all comments but set the `user_id` to null if the user isn't logged in. Since every comment should have a `user_id` no comments will be returned.

```
$posts = Post::select('posts.*')
    ->with(['comments' => function($query) {
            $query->where('user_id', Auth::check() ? Auth::id() : null);
    }])
    ->get();
```

The code in the second one looks cleaner IMO, but the first one will prevent an unnecessary query from being executed.

Answer (score 2):

you can do a little trick in your post model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
public function comments()
{
    if(Auth::check()) {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Comment')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
    }else{
         return $this->hasMany('App\Comment')->where('user_id',-1);
    }
}
```

}

and then simply :

```
$posts = Post::select('posts.*')->with('comments')->get()
```

so if user is not logged in it will return all comments with user_id of "-1" which will be nothing

Answer (score 1):

You can separate it, more legible and practical:

```
$posts = Post::all();
```

At your Post model create a function that will return all user's comments:

```
public function userComments()
{
    return $this->comments->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
}
```

And i guess at your view you have a foreach to iterate all posts, inside your foreach you load post's comments, so you can do that:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    $post->userComments()
@endforeach
```

Comment: I should mention that the results I want to return are for my API, and therefore I don't make use of blade views. For that reason, I need to eager load the results.